# how to get coordinates of button with respect to superview?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

My view hierarchy is

UIViewController.view

a subview (on main view with half size and in bottom)

a button on this subview

I want to get the co-ordinates of this button with respect to my main view

the CGRect of this button but according to superview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[self.view convertRect:button.frame fromView:button.superview];
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 [view convertPoint:thePoint toView:subview];
```